# Non-defined sized array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am learning C using learn-c.org, and on [this page](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Strings) it says I can use

```
char name[] = "John"
```

In its own example on the bottom frame of the page, if I do

```
char last_name[] = "Doe"
```

no errors are reported but the program won't run.  It will only run if I do `char last_name[4]` or greater... so the question:

Can an array be declared without a size or do I need to know the max values the array will hold?  So kind of a second question, if I do `int array[10]`, what would happen if I needed more than 10 values?

Comment: Please post the code you've written for this.

Comment: On that learn-c link page, I've replaced the comments on lines 4 and 5 with:
    char * first_name = "John";
    char last_name[] = "Doe";

But that doesn't work, only the following does:

    char * first_name = "John";
    char last_name[4] = "Doe";

Comment: An array is always declared with a size, but you don't always have to spell out the size in the source code.

Comment: @GavinBurke It works. You must have accidentally erased some character when typing.

Comment: I've got it working on my own machine, needed to include string.h then needed a third argument to strncmp and now the "char last_name[]" works (ofc with a = <value> ;  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can an array be declared without a size or do I need to know the max
>   values the array will hold?

Depends on whether you initialize it. When you initialize it, the compiler will count the elements for you. So, this is valid:

```
int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

This effectively creates an array of 4 elements. If you provide a size *and* initialize the array, then if the size is greater than the number of elements, the first elements are initialized accordingly, and the rest of them are initialized to their default initialization value (0 for integers, null for pointers, etc.).

If the size is less than the number of elements, it is an error.

If you do not initialize, then you have to declare the size.

With this:

```
char last_name[] = "Doe";
```

The compiler creates an array of 4 chars (one of them is the null terminator).

> If I do int array[10], what would happen if I needed more than 10
>   values?

You can't do anything. If you need more than 10, you need a bigger array.

Comment: If the above was true, my char name[] = "John" should therefore calculate itself rather than showing nothing on my printf output...?

Comment: @GavinBurke Please show your code so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: @GavinBurke Are you sure you terminated that declaration with `;`? You keep talking about `char name[] = "John"`, but it should be `char name[] = "John";`

Comment: I have just tried on my PC instead of that website and it works, my .exe outputs Done! so I guess it's that website being crud... thanks Filipe!

Answer (score -2):

You can either have an array with fixed size or a pointer to an array (starts with *) that can have any size (up to its limits that is).

As for the second question, the program would crash as the array would get out of its boundaries.

Comment: So for me to declare an array without a size, I use     char * name instead?

Comment: This is wrong. A pointer to an array cannot point to an array of any size. Pointers to arrays are tied to their size. For example, a pointer to an array of 10 integers is of type `int (*)[10]`. Maybe you wanted to say that pointers to dynamic memory can be used as an alternative to arrays when the array size is not known at compile-time.